# Playing animated gif with libgdx

Tags: android, ios, animation, libgdx, animated-gif

How to play animated gif file with libgdx?

I know it uses [spriteanimation](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteAnimation), but I need to play **GIF** files because they save a lot of space.

It is okay if I have to use/build a [decoder like this](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/15/tutorial-how-to-play-animated-gifs-in-android-%E2%80%93-part-2/). But I need it for libgdx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
There is a solution to this problem:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=10351&p=46673#p46673

Looks like there is no direct way to play animated gifs in libgdx.

Comment: Please include an example of the linked code in action.